# Git : Merge Issue

Tags: git, github

i have three branch :

```
Integration -> Staging -> Production
```

in my local machine i have setup integration branch so when i changed anything in local then i push that code in integration and then merge integration into staging and then staging into production. That is what i followed this process.

now my issue is , two day ago i have done 3 commit in integration and also merge that commit into staging only. this staging was remain to merge into production. but when i coming on next day i have seen that `some other developer has directly push the code in production branch.`

so now i need to merge my commit into production branch and also need to stay their other developer commit on production as well update on other branch also.
so how can i do that and how to continue my work flow what i have used before ?

Please share if anyone have idea..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have commits done in production by others, you will need to rebase staging onto the new production branch.
That is, assuming you have not push yet staging.

```
i--i--i      (int)
       \
     s--S    (staging)
      \
       P--np (prod)
```

np is the commit(s) directly pushed to prod

```
git checkout staging
git fetch
git rebase --preserve-merge origin/prod
git push
```

That is:

```
      i'--i'--i'      (int)
               \
     s       ---S'    (staging)
      \     /
       P--np (prod)
```

If staging was not pushed yet, you can simply push it back: it will be based on the latest prod branch, including the latest commit directly pushed on prod.

Comment: how can i update that other developer code in my local machine ( integration branch) and my all commit already push on staging.

Comment: Then merge back staging to integration, after rebasing staging on top of prod: you will have everything then